# Create concatenated .d.ts with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'd wish to build my TypeScript project (in Visual Studio) with the following automated steps:

1. compile each `.ts` file as an AMD module, separately
2. bundle each created `.js` file with webpack, into `release/my-app.js`

As part of step 1, `.d.ts` files are also created for each `.ts` file (in addition to the output Javascript files). How may I bundle these definition files together as well, so that they provide type definitions for what gets bundled into the `my-app.js` output file?

---

**project layout**

```
MyApp
|-- lib
|   |-- foo.ts
|   |-- foo.js
|   |-- foo.d.ts
|   `-- ...
|-- release
|   `-- my-app.js
|-- main.ts
|-- main.js
|-- main.d.ts
`-- webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'release'),
        filename: 'my-app.js'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-bundle, but this is experimental and it does not work well with **awesome-typescript-loader**.